# Build a .NET solution from PowerShell

Tags: visual-studio-2010, powershell

How do I build a .NET solution from the PowerShell command prompt?

Comment: Possibly answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560652/why-does-powershell-fail-to-build-my-net-solutions-file-is-being-used-by-ano?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to call `msbuild.exe` passing in the solution file and appropriate arguments and do the build.

Also have a look at YDeliver ( https://github.com/manojlds/YDeliver )  for a build framework in Powershell. (Work in progress)

Comment: So how do I create a starter for PowerShell with the environmental variables needed for MSBuild? I know one comes for the normal command shell, but I don't know how to port it.

Comment: @JonathanAllen - MSBuild doesn't require any environment variables. The visual studio command prompt puts it on the path, but I don't think it does anything else.